# My Wordpress Website's Homepage shows godaddy page and all other pages are working fine

Tags: wordpress, dns, host

I have a wordpress website which after completion, hosted on hostinger. The problem is the homepage automatically shows the godaddy page which I have not created. Else all other pages are working fine. Someone can here can please help me out with this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check you are installed WordPress site in root directory (https://example.com) or in sub-directory (https://example.com/wp/). If installed in subdirectory, consider re-install or change to root directory and change URL in database. MySQL query will be like -

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'oldurl.com', 'newurl.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'oldurl.com','newurl.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'oldurl.com', 'newurl.com');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'oldurl.com','newurl.com');
```

Hope this help.